# Method chaining in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sproutcore

This working code is using Sproutcore:

```
person = SC.Object.create({
    firstName: 'Foo',
    lastName: 'Bar',
    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + " " + this.get('lastName');
    }.property()

});

console.log(person.get('fullName')); // "Foo Bar"
```

I wonder where property() is declared and how they have made this to work.
When I try to reconstruct this without the SC class, it gives me:

```
TypeError: Object function () {
        return this.get('firstName') + " " + this.get('lastName');
    } has no method 'property'
```

How does the code looks like to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sproutcore is extending the function prototype.

```
Function.prototype.property = function() { /* code here */ };
```

The specific code use by sproutcore is at https://github.com/sproutcore/sproutcore/blob/master/frameworks/runtime/core.js#L908

```
SC.mixin(Function.prototype, 
//...snip...

property: function() {
    this.dependentKeys = SC.$A(arguments) ;
    var guid = SC.guidFor(this) ;
    this.cacheKey = "__cache__" + guid ;
    this.lastSetValueKey = "__lastValue__" + guid ;
    this.isProperty = YES ;
    return this ;
  },
//snip
);
```

In their case, they are using their own mixin method, but the concept is the same: extending the prototype

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, Sproutcode has modified `Function.prototype` to include a `property` function.

You could just look at [the source code](https://github.com/sproutcore/sproutcore).

Comment: Yeah im new to programming. How am I supposed to know where the code for this resides?

Comment: @weng: http://www.google.com, or just look at the SproutCore web site (also found through Google) http://www.sproutcore.com/documentation/

Comment: @weng: oh! sorry. Well, that's what github search is for. Unfortunately, it seems to be down right now: https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=javascript&q=Function.prototype.property+repo:sproutcore/sproutcore&repo=&langOverride=&x=18&y=25&start_value=1